# VS 2013 Create Per-User Publishing Settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

We've recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 and we're having some issues with the new way publishing is handled.  Previously, (in VS 2010) every user had their own local publishing settings, but in VS 2013 it's changed to the idea of shared publish settings.  This is causing problems with our environment because every developer has a different local dev environment (paths, connection strings, email addresses to send things to).  I realize this is not the optimal way to have things set up, but that's the reality of our situation right now.

We use config transforms to handle the various web.config changes for different developers, so just running through VS doesn't work for us because it doesn't run the transforms.  This also causes a problem with the VS 2013 publish settings because the last build config used is stored in the shared publish settings.  In order to keep all our settings different, it looks like we're going to need to have a different publish setting for each developer now as well (such as "Local - Erik", "Local - OtherDev").  This is just going further down a path I'd like to get out of eventually.

So my question boils down to: Is it possible to somehow disable the shared profile settings? I thought of just not including them in version control, but then Visual Studio complains that the files are missing on other developers' systems.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by excluding the profile from the project after you create it.  The publish wizard looks for any profile on disk, but newly created ones are added to the project by default.  If you then exclude the .pubxml file from the project and remove it from source control, it shouldn't bother you again.

Comment: Is it possible to make it forget about publish profiles in general?  I have a feeling someone will forget to exclude the profile every time they create a new one and VS will keep adding them back.

Comment: @ErikDavidson Not that I know of.  I know the (uncustomizable) default is to add the profile to the project, which will also add it to source control.  If it does get checked in accidentally, it's still a manual fix to exclude it from the project and remove it from your VCS.  Oh, and if removing it from VCS deletes the file (in TFS this is usually the case) then you also want to copy it or bring it back somehow so you don't have to recreate it in VS again.

Comment: @ErikDavidson Depending on your source control, you could add an ignore rule for .pubxml (e.g. in a .gitignore or .tfignore).  You might end up with noise in the project file if someone forgets to exclude it, but that's a lot easier to fix up.  For more info on .tfignore (since it's a recent feature) see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx#tfignore.

Comment: We're using SVN to do it and I could set SVN to ignore those files, but I still really don't like the current solution (not your fault)!  I guess I'll just have to live with it for now and really push to get developers set up with the same environments locally so we don't have to worry about this problem in the first place.  I also did some looking around to see if I could somehow write an extension for VS to have it not add profiles to the project, but it didn't look like that was currently possible. Thanks for your help, though!